# How to get uniq report with the below access log

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

Input

```
Severity: Warning   Missing argument 1 for Pxxer_rzxczt_v3::mast() /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 115/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
Severity: Warning   Missing argument 1 for Pxxer_rzxczt_v3::mast() /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 115/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
Severity: Warning   Missing argument 1 for Pxxer_rzxczt_v3::mast() /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 115/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
Severity: Notice   Undefined variable: vedwe erwer rew  /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/wefwf/efe/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 130/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
Severity: Notice   Undefined variable: vedwe erwer rew  /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/wefwf/efe/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 130/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
Severity: Notice   Undefined variable: vCode /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 130/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
Severity: Notice   Undefined variable: vCode /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 130/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
Severity: Notice   Undefined variable: vCode /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 130/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/
```

Output

```
Severity: Warning   Missing argument 1 for Pxxer_rzxczt_v3::mast() /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 115  - 3  
Severity: Notice   Undefined variable: vCode /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 130   -  3   
Severity: Notice   Undefined variable: vedwe erwer rew  /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/wefwf/efe/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 130   -  2
```

Comment: You may be interested in `man uniq`.

Comment: uniq or sort anything am fine.

Comment: just do `sort input.txt | uniq`

Comment: Mind that you are talking to humans. Input, Output is not enough to communicate with humans. Learn how to behave here!!

Answer (score 0):

The [uniq](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq) unix command does what you want, with the -c option.

`cat yourlog | uniq -c` will output

```
   1 everity: Warning   Missing argument 1 for Pxxer_rzxczt_v3::mast() /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 115/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
   2 Severity: Warning   Missing argument 1 for Pxxer_rzxczt_v3::mast() /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 115/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
   2 Severity: Notice   Undefined variable: vedwe erwer rew  /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/wefwf/efe/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 130/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/  
   3 Severity: Notice   Undefined variable: vCode /sdfdsfv/ddw/hdd/nddd/system/adsdn/codsds/pr_rt_v3.php 130/dadm/index.php/plasdasd/mast/
```

This will however make repeated lines that are not directly repeated after each other to be counted up on different lines.

For example the input:

```
foo
foo
bar
bar
foo
foo
```

will give the output:

```
2 foo
2 bar
2 foo
```

If you want the output to be

```
2 bar
4 foo
```

you would first have to sort the file, like this:

```
cat yourlog | sort | uniq -c
```