# Uniq report from apache log

Tags: awk, uniq

**Input**

```
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: PID /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 208/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Warning  --> Missing argument 1 for pv::mast() /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 115/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/   
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: vCode /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 130/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: vCode /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 155/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: vCode /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 155/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: vCode /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 155/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: PID /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 208/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: VIDEOID /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 209/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: PLAYERID /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 210/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: PLAYERID /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 210/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: FILEFILTERS /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 211/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: PLAYERID /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 210/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Warning  --> Missing argument 1 for pv::mast() /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 115/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Warning  --> Missing argument 1 for pv::mast() /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 115/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: FILEFILTERS /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 211/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: FILEFILTERS /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 211/newplatform/index.php/pv/mast/
```

**Output:**

```
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Warning  --> Missing argument 1 for pv::mast() /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 115 - 3  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: vCode /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 130 -2  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: vCode /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 155 - 3   
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: PID /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 208 - 2  
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: VIDEOID /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 209 -1   
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: PLAYERID /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 210 - 3   
ERROR - 2015-05-26 15:25:18 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: FILEFILTERS /ad/www/dsds/dsd/dff/fddfd/controllers/pv.php 211  - 3
```

Comment: already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454601/how-to-get-uniq-report-with-the-below-access-log

Comment: Mind that you are talking to humans. Input, Output is not enough to communicate with humans. Also you have asked this before. Learn how to behave here!!